# iTunes Match hangs at step 2 and does not complete

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I have been trying to get iTunes Match to work for a week. It keeps getting stuck at Step 2.  To try and fix it I have been stopping and starting Match, sometimes it gets further and other times it doesn't get as far.

Today I have another problem, when I start iTunes Match it gives this error

"We could not complete your iTunes Store request. An unknown error has occurred (4002)."

Now I can't start iTunes Match all.  Have to say I am very disappointed with how difficult it is to make this service work.

-- Edit --

I left iTunes Match running overnight. This morning iTunes had "quit unexpectedly".  Now it is starting all over again (sigh).

Answer (score 1):

- Open iTunes. Click the “Store" Menu Drop Down.
- **While holding down** <kbd>Option</kbd> click "Turn Off iTunes Match”
- Reboot your machine.
- Open iTunes. Without holding option, click the “Store” Menu Drop down again > "Turn on iTunes Match”

It should now run as expected.

Comment: This seems to be the solution in the majority of iTunes Match problems.  Turn it off and turn it on again.

Answer (score 0):

The error just means some kind of network issue connecting to the server. It could be almost anything and perhaps 2 minutes later it will try again and succeed.

I also just started using iTunes Match and found the progress bar is terrible. For me it was working in the background, but takes a very long time and the status/progress bar is useless - it doesn't tell you what is actually happening.

I suggest just leaving iTunes running and ignore it. Match should already be working for almost all of your library and will eventually have all songs (it may take days).

See my answer to this question with more details: [iTunes Match is stuck on the last song in step 2 of the initial process](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31706/itunes-match-is-stuck-on-the-last-song-in-step-2-of-the-initial-process/98159#98159)

Comment: The 4002 error has stopped now, but again it gets so far through step 2 and then stops. Activity Monitor says iTunes isn't doing anything (about 0.5% CPU).  Each time I re-run its progress is different, sometimes better sometimes worse.

Comment: What about network activity in activity monitor? Mine did the same thing, and the CPU was idle but my upstream network was maxed out for several hours, and still only half done when I closed iTunes at the end of the day.

Comment: Insignificant network activity, certainly not what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Is your iTunes latest version? It does not happen when iTunes 11 but it does when I run the update to iTunes 12, quite strange.